# Relative Abundance Errors

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I have a bag with colored balls inside it. For every 1 red ball in the bag there are 2 blue balls and 3 green balls. (1: 2: 3 ratio)

I draw 10 balls from the bag and find 2 red balls, 3 blue balls and 5 green balls, from this I calculate a 1: 1.5: 2.5 ratio. How do I describe the error on my calculated ratio? I understand it should go as $(\mbox{number of draws})^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ , but I'm not sure if there are any other terms here.

Comment: What is the variable $n$?

Comment: the number of draws, I'll edit the question to clarify

Comment: If in the bin there are $r$ red, $2r$ blue, $3r$ green, and you pick $10k$ balls (where $10k \leq 6r$),  the probability that there are $2k$ red, $3k$ blue, $5k$ green is $$ \frac{{r \choose 2k}{2r \choose 3k}{3r \choose 5k}}{{6r \choose 10k}}$$

Comment: If $r\rightarrow\infty$ so the bin has infinite balls and the probability of picking a red is $1/6$,  independent every pick, then of $n$ picks you can define the random variable $R$ as the number of reds picked. Then $\frac{R-n/6}{\sqrt{n}}$ approaches a Gaussian distribution with variance $(1/6)(5/6)$, and this can be viewed as a scaled "error about the mean." You could also use the Chebyshev or Chernov-Hoeffding inequality to calculate a bound on $P[|R-n/6|\geq \epsilon]$. Or use a multivariate central limit theorem to show $(R-n/6, B-n/3)/\sqrt{n}$ converges to a jointly Gaussian dist.